# Rigify says "RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'spine.004': Cannot connect chain - bone position is disjoint. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'"

Tags: modeling, rigging, error, rigify

I saw a video about this issue and followed through with it and made sure the bones are connected and have a parent/child relationship, however even though they are connected and marked as connected as well as marked as parented error still persists. If any specifics are needed I can provide when asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem arises when the tail of the last spine bone is not exaclty in the same spot as the head of the first neck bone.

To solve, select the Metarig, go to edit mode, select the head of spine.004, Shift S > Cursor to selected, select the tail of spine.003 > Shift S > Selection to cursor.

Comment: I tried your solution and unfortunately for some reason I still have said error. I should note the bones on the rig are moved around to fit a non human type model. So I don't know if that would have a huge effect on it, but I'm assuming it at least has some.

Comment: I decided just to delete the first set of bones and generate another one after making the second set I made sure to keep all the bones together and just move them how I saw fit afterwards the rig was able to generate properly.